# Is it possible to manually extract and print Pokemon Snap pictures?

Tags: pokemon-snap

There was that thing when Pokemon Snap was new that made it possible to go to I think Blockbuster and print your photos.

Is it possible to do it from home now? Like if I have the means to drop my rom from my cartridge to my PC could I then extract the photos and use them like a JPEG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The N64 version could be taken to [Blockbuster or Lawson stores in North America or Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Snap) to print the photos.

If you can load the game on your PC, then you can screenshot the photos as you would normally on a PC such as with the Print Screen button. Then you can use the screenshots as JPEGs.

The Wii and Wii U Virtual Console version photos could be used for sharing in the message boards and photo channels, [but could not be saved and treated like usual JPEG files](https://pokemondb.net/pokebase/307087/save-pictures-from-pokemon-snap-into-your-computers-local-file).

Comment: Your solution does work but screenshotting will also get the full square around the photo. I can't remember a way to fullscreen a photo for the biggest photo possible.